# Sequential Bayesian estimation of binary outcome

Tags: bayesian, estimation, binomial-distribution

I am planning an experiment to determine the frequency of a binary variable (valued 1 or 0).

Each day, there are ~ 10,000 new events taking place, thought this number may shift by ~ 100 day to day.

Each day, I get to draw ~ 70 to ~100 randomly out of the new ~ 10,000 and see their outcome (either 1 or 0)

How do I estimate the frequency of 1 and 0 in the population with this data, updating my estimate every day? Would this be considered a Bayesian approach to estimation?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bayesian approach. If you want to know the parameter p of a Bernouilli distribution, in the Bayesian approach, you start with a distribution of this parameter p, called the prior distribution. You use for this a Beta distribution. It is standard to start with a Beta(1,1) if you don't know much about p. In a sequential procedure, given data, your Beta distribution will change its parameters. If you have N new points with p ones and N-p zeros, your Beta distribution will be now B(1+p,1+N-p). This is the posterior distribution, and you can use it again as a prior distribution when you have more data.